# a JAR-like archive format for python?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've got a python project in pyDev (eclipse for python), that has the following files:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── libs
│   └── easygui
│       ├── easygui.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── licence.txt
└── __main__.py
```

I can run the program with `python3 project`, but then I'd have to distribute a whole folder when I put it on my website for download. I'd like to package it all into a JAR-style archive file, so I can run it with `python3 project.pya` or whatever file extention, and only have to distribute one file.
is there such a file format?
thanks,
martin

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Python has [wheels](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/peps/#pep427s). Instructions are [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html).